# Getting "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading" when trying to upload a file to tmp_name

Tags: php, file, upload

I'm making a site to store mp3 files in a database. When I go to the site, it says that I successfully connected to the database and that I successfully selected the database. But then when I select a file and press the Upload button, it tries to connect for a long time before my web browser says "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading" The code that is commented out isn't working. EDIT: It may be relevant that I'm using a hosting service.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- HTML5 style -->
<html lan="en">
<head>
<title>Upload Music</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form action="UploadMusic.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File:
    <input type="file" name="music"/> <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>

<?php
$DBConnect = mysql_connect("replaced", "for", "privacy");
     if ($DBConnect === FALSE) {
         echo "Did not successfully connect to the database server." . 
         "<p>Error code " . mysql_errno()
               . ": " . mysql_error() . "</p>";
     }
     else {
         echo "<p>Successfully connected to the database server</p>";
         if (mysql_select_db("replaced") === FALSE) {
             echo "Did not successfully select the database";
         }
         else {
             echo "Successfully selected the database";
             /*$file = $_FILES["music"]["tmp_name"];
             echo $file;
             if (!isset($file)) {
                 echo "Please select a mp3 file to upload";
             }
             else {
                 $music = file_get_contents($_FILES["music"]["tmp_name"]);
                 echo $music;
             }
             */

        }
    }
?>  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The file size was too large for my hosting service.